# Github Action use matrices with reuse-able workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I've been rooting through the Github Action documentation around re-useable workflows and am attempting to piece together a chain of matrices.

My pseudo workflow looks something like the following steps.

- Job 1: Figure out files changed under a path & output them as json
- Job 2: Iterate the file list as a matrix and invoke another workflow.
- Job 3 (in other workflow): Simply use another matrix definition in conjunction with the single input value to perform a set of steps.

It would seem a relatively simple objective. Yet it looks like workflow re-useable calls do not support `strategy`. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GitHub Actions matrix supports now reusable workflows (since 22.08.22):

```
jobs:
  ReuseableMatrixJobForDeployment:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        target: [dev, stage, prod]
    uses: octocat/octo-repo/.github/workflows/deployment.yml@main
    with:
      target: ${{ matrix.target }}
```

**References:**

- [GitHub Actions: Improvements to reusable workflows](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-22-github-actions-improvements-to-reusable-workflows-2/#:%7E:text=Reusable%20workflows%20can%20now%20be,richer%20parameterized%20builds%20and%20deployments.)
- [Using a matrix strategy with a reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-a-matrix-strategy-with-a-reusable-workflow)

Answer (score 4):

edit: The situation has changed since posting this. There is now an accepted answer.

It appears matrix (strategy) can't be used with reusable actions, at least right now. See [GH Actions docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/reusing-workflows#supported-keywords-for-jobs-that-call-a-reusable-workflow).

Given that reusable actions [went GA literally yesterday](https://github.blog/2021-11-29-github-actions-reusable-workflows-is-generally-available/), I expect this might eventually change. Notice the announcement shows an example with a `matrix`... And the replacement conveniently leaves out what's being called.

As far as I understand it, the limitation can be rephrased as "you can't write a C style for loop" - you can't have the caller workflow use `strategy` on a job that is a reusable action call. However you can reverse the relationship: Move `strategy` into the reused workflow (callee). Then, you can also pass in the matrix in `inputs` as a JSON encoded in a string. See the [discussion about this workaround](https://github.community/t/reusable-workflow-with-strategy-matrix/205676).

That's certainly not good enough for me, but judge yourself.

Comment: The link to the discussion is now dead. GitHub docs describe this workaround at https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-returning-a-json-object